# Segmentation fault во время вызова memcpy

Tags: c, указатели, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct array
{
    int* p;
};

int main()
{
    struct array* a;

    int b[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) b[i] = i;

    a->p = (int*) malloc(5);

    memcpy(a->p, b, 5);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d ", b[i]);

    return 0;
}      

//Segmentation fault ( Whats wrong?
```

Answer (score 2):

Указатель `a` не инициализирован

Answer (score -1):

Нужно изменить код следующим образом:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
```

Comment: и в чём разница?

Comment: printf of a[i] not the b[i].
thanks Vlad.
mistake was in third argument of memcpy

Comment: @ИгорьИгоревичМусинов If you think that the question is resolved then close it selecting the best answer.